# parsing json in sencha touch 2

Tags: android, json, extjs

I was trying  to parse the json data , to list in for android app
The response is as follows

```
{"records":[{"reg_no":"444444","name":"xyz, pqr","address":"Kathmandu-64, Kathmandu","sex":"Male","qualification":"B..E","university":"T.U","year":"2010","faculty":"Computer","date":"2012-08-17 11:29:38"}]}
```

Sencha code is as follows

```
{
                    xtype: 'nestedlist',
                    title: 'List',
                    iconCls: 'star',
                    displayField: 'name',

                    store: {
                        type: 'tree',

                        fields: [
                            'name', 'reg_no', 'faculty', 'address', 'university',
                            {name: 'leaf', defaultValue: true}
                        ],

                        root: {
                            leaf: false
                        },

                        proxy: {
                            type: 'jsonp',
                            url: 'http://timus.com/api.php?name=serish',
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                rootProperty: 'records'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    detailCard: {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        scrollable: true,
                        styleHtmlContent: true
                    },

                    listeners: {
                        itemtap: function(nestedList, list, index, element, post) {
                            this.getDetailCard().setHtml(post.get('university'));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

but is not parsing json.. the followong error is coming

**`uncaught syntax error : unexpected token`**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and reading some articles I realize that the proxy type must be "rest" if the url is a restful service.

I saw at: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader